# MAX Date Less Than Another Date

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to determine the count of attendance for a training course between 2007-2013. I need it to pull the employees job group they were in during the time frame:

```
SELECT O867IA_VJOBHST.JOB_CLS_CD, O867IA_VJOBHST.DIS_NR, 
Sum(IIf(emp_tng_stt_dt Between #1/1/2007# And #12/31/2011#,1,0)) AS [2007-2011], 
Sum(IIf(emp_tng_stt_dt Between #1/1/2011# And #12/31/2011#,1,0)) AS 2011, 
Sum(IIf(emp_tng_stt_dt Between #1/1/2012# And #12/31/2012#,1,0)) AS 2012, 
Sum(IIf(emp_tng_stt_dt Between #1/1/2013# And #9/23/2013#,1,0)) AS 2013, O867IA_VJOBHST.REC_EFF_STT_DT, O867IA_VTRAING.EMP_TNG_STT_DT
FROM (O867IA_VJOBHST INNER JOIN O867IA_VTRAING ON O867IA_VJOBHST.SYS_EMP_ID_NR = O867IA_VTRAING.SYS_EMP_ID_NR) INNER JOIN O867IA_VPJOBCO ON O867IA_VJOBHST.JOB_CLS_CD = O867IA_VPJOBCO.JOB_CLS_CD
WHERE (((O867IA_VTRAING.REG_NR)="03") AND ((O867IA_VTRAING.TNG_SYS_NR)="0918") AND ((O867IA_VPJOBCO.JOB_GRP_CD)="61"))
GROUP BY O867IA_VJOBHST.JOB_CLS_CD, O867IA_VJOBHST.DIS_NR, O867IA_VJOBHST.REC_EFF_STT_DT, O867IA_VTRAING.EMP_TNG_STT_DT;
```

The REC_EFF_STT_DT field is the date they were recorded in their job, so I am trying to get that to be the MAX date, and it needs to be less than EMP_TNG_STT_DT which is when the training course was held. I try set it up like (((O867IA_VJOBHST.REC_EFF_STT_DT)<[O867IA_VTRAING].[EMP_TNG_STT_DT])); but it keeps giving me an error "you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression" whenever I add the MAX to REC EFF STT DT. I cannot find any solutions and need assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If your `((MAX(O867IA_VJOBHST.REC_EFF_STT_DT) < [O867IA_VTRAING].[EMP_TNG_STT_DT]))` is giving you this error, then perhaps it is also in your `SELECT` list, and is not just a 'Where`clause.  Try removing it from your`SELECT` list.

Another suggestion is that `[O867IA_VTRAING].[EMP_TNG_STT_DT]` is not aggregated.  You may be able to get this to work by aggregating that too.  If you want the unaltered value, a `FIRST()` may work.